# Why does my neural network not learn the XOR problem?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, xor

Im new to pytorch and tried to learn the XOR Problem (with some noise).

Of course I know that i have to use multiple layers and a non-linearity in between. But my network still doesn't learn anything, so I assume there is a mistake in my pytorch code. The weights just don't change at all. Please Help!

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs #for data generation
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import torch

X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=200, n_features=2, cluster_std=.1
                  ,centers= [(1,1), (1,0), (0,0),(0,1)])
y[y==2]=0
y[y==3]=1

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=19)

#np->torch
x_train = torch.FloatTensor(x_train)
x_test = torch.FloatTensor(x_test)
y_train = torch.FloatTensor(y_train)
y_test = torch.FloatTensor(y_test)

class XOR(torch.nn.Module): 
    def __init__(self): 
        super(XOR, self).__init__()
        self.layer1 = torch.nn.Linear(2,2)
        self.layer2 = torch.nn.Linear(2, 1)
        self.non_linear = torch.nn.Sigmoid() 
    def forward(self, x): 
        output = self.layer1(x)
        output = self.non_linear(output)
        output = self.layer2(output)
        output = self.non_linear(output)
        return output

model = XOR()
criterion = torch.nn.BCELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr = 0.01)

model.train() #set to train mode
epoch = 50
for e in range(epoch):
    # Forward pass
    y_pred = model(x_train)
    # Compute Loss
    loss = criterion(y_pred.flatten(), y_train)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    print('Epoch {}: train loss: {}'.format(e, loss.item()))
    # Backward pass
    loss.backward()
    #make gradient update
    optimizer.step()

model.eval() #set model to eval mode

#train 
y_pred = model(x_train) #predict
y_pred=(y_pred>0.5).int().flatten() #argmax class lable
train_acc = torch.sum(y_pred == y_train.int())/y_train.shape[0]
print("train ACC: ",train_acc.float())

#test 
y_pred = model(x_test) #predict
y_pred=(y_pred>0.5).int().flatten() #argmax class lable
test_acc = torch.sum(y_pred == y_test.int())/y_test.shape[0]
print("test ACC: ",test_acc.float())
```

I tried to increase lr, add more layers and add more neurons. None of it worked

Comment: Perceptron can't solve it.  This article is interesting.  Not sure if it helps your problem: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-neural-networks-solve-the-xor-problem-59763136bdd7

Comment: I used a MLP, didnt I?

Comment: Yes.  The article gives a lot of background and goes through the solution for NN.

Comment: So I still don't understand how my solution isn't working :/

Comment: Oh well.  This isn't a "fix my problem on command" site.  I'll run it and see what I can find.

Comment: PyCharm doesn't like your lines 58 or 63 very much: "Expected type Tensor got bool instead".  Don't know if that's your problem, but I pay attention when PyCharm tells me about potential problems.

Comment: Try removing the nonlinearity on the output. You just need the one in the middle to make it non-linear. :-) Also BCE might not be a great loss here. Consider MSE.

Answer (score 1):

Technically there's nothing wrong with your approach. You just have a very tiny dataset (gradient estimates are poor) with a small learning rate (moving too slowly to global min) for too few epochs (not moving close enough to the global min). If you change any of these, you'll see immediate improvements. That said, if you want to approach this more realistically, here are some observations/suggestions.

## Your non-linearity isn't a very good choice.

Sigmoid is typically a non-linearity applied to an output layer for classification tasks; consider ReLU. Sigmoid applied to hidden layers can make gradients vanish which becomes a massive information bottleneck in backprop.

## Your hidden size is far too small.

You can achieve better than random performance with a hidden size of 2, but larger values will get you much further much faster.

## Consider using MSE and removing the output non-linearity.

Treating this as a regression problem instead of classification will make it easier to learn. You can use BCE, but it'll take much longer because the information is more sparse.

## Your learning rate is too low.

This is an easy problem with a pretty neat loss landscape. Take big steps!

Here's my final code (which achieves perfect train and test acc):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs #for data generation
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import torch

X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=200, n_features=2, cluster_std=.1
                  ,centers= [(1,1), (1,0), (0,0),(0,1)])

y[y==2]=0
y[y==3]=1

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=19)


#np->torch
x_train = torch.FloatTensor(x_train)
x_test = torch.FloatTensor(x_test)
y_train = torch.FloatTensor(y_train)
y_test = torch.FloatTensor(y_test)

class XOR(torch.nn.Module): 
    def __init__(self): 
        super(XOR, self).__init__()
        self.layer1 = torch.nn.Linear(2,10)
        self.layer2 = torch.nn.Linear(10, 1)
        self.non_linear = torch.nn.ReLU() 

    def forward(self, x): 
        output = self.layer1(x)
        output = self.non_linear(output)
        output = self.layer2(output)
        return output

model = XOR()
criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr = 0.1)

model.train() #set to train mode
epoch = 100
for e in range(epoch):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    # Forward pass
    y_pred = model(x_train)
    # Compute Loss
    loss = criterion(y_pred.squeeze(), y_train)
    print('Epoch {}: train loss: {}'.format(e, loss.item()))
    # Backward pass
    loss.backward()
    #make gradient update
    optimizer.step()

model.eval() #set model to eval mode

#train 
y_pred = model(x_train) #predict

y_pred=(y_pred>0.5).int().flatten() #argmax class lable
train_acc = torch.mean((y_pred == y_train.int()).float())
print("train ACC: ",train_acc.float())

#test 
y_pred = model(x_test) #predict
y_pred=(y_pred>0.5).int().flatten() #argmax class lable
test_acc = torch.mean((y_pred == y_test.int()).float())
print("test ACC: ",test_acc.float())
```

Comment: I was able to get perfect train and test accuracy from MLP classifier.  Felt like overfitting to me.  Interesting to try and optimize.  Your suggestions were excellent - well informed.

Comment: I don't think it's overfitting---just a very easy problem. It's artificially easy because we're cheating by setting the `cluster_std` at the _entire dataset_ level. If the test set had a different distribution, it might be a bit harder. :-)

Comment: Thanks man! I still dont really get why its not possible with 2 hidden neurons and/or sigmoid cause I can manually find weights with which it works, and there are blogs solving the XOR-problem (without noise) with my architecture, but anyways... thanks!

Comment: You can, you just need to increase the number of epochs to a _very large_ number. Your problem has a few confounders: small dataset size (so gradient estimates are poor), tiny learning rate (so many steps required to get good optima). Because the number of epoch is relatively small, you can't hope to find a global minimum. Increase epochs to 50k for fun and see what happens to your acc. :-) should be quick on CPU. Then increase your lr by an order of magnitude and try again.

Comment: Maybe in short: there's nothing wrong with your net from a _correctness_ perspective, but it's certainly not an optimal architecture (slow to converge, sensitive to train).

Comment: thank you so much, that really cleared my mind... As a mathematician i am very familiar with theoretical points of machine learning, but i am just starting to learn how to really implement models. And i realised there is a huuuge difference and i am still such a noob. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got some different results by swapping in the SK Learn multi-layer perceptron:

```
# see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75898473/why-does-my-neural-network-not-learn-the-xor-problem?noredirect=1#comment133873645_75898473

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

if __name__ == '__main__':

    X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=200, n_features=2, cluster_std=.1, centers= [(1,1), (1,0), (0,0),(0,1)])
    y[y == 2] = 0
    y[y == 3] = 1

    plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, s=25, edgecolors='k')
    plt.show()

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=19)

    model = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=20, learning_rate='adaptive', epsilon=0.01)
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)

    #train
    y_pred_train = model.predict(X_train)
    plt.scatter(X_train[:, 0], X_train[:, 1], c=y_train, s=25, edgecolors='k')
    plt.show()
    train_acc = np.sum(y_pred_train == y_train)/y_train.shape[0]
    print("train accuracy: ", train_acc)

    #test
    y_pred_test = model.predict(X_test)
    plt.scatter(X_test[:, 0], X_test[:, 1], c=y_test, s=25, edgecolors='k')
    plt.show()
    test_acc = np.sum(y_pred_test == y_test)/y_test.shape[0]
    print("test  accuracy: ", test_acc)
```

Here are the results:

```
train accuracy:  0.8134328358208955
test  accuracy:  0.7727272727272727
```

Scatter plot for train:

[image]

Scatter plot for test:

[image]

Could play around the hidden layers and epsilon to see what effect they have on accuracy.

I can make both train and test accuracies equal to 1.0 if I take the default values for `MLPClassifier`, but I'm sure it's just overfitting and memorizing the data.